# Compare ListViewItems with SelectedItems

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have the following Problem:

I have a ListView with e.g. 5 items:

```
AAAA (selected)
BBBB 
CCCC (selected)
AAAA (selected)
AAAA
```

And I will check if all the same items are selected (there can also be additional items selected here the CCCC for example) if not then I will get an Msgbox with en error message.

In this example it should get the error messag because one AAAA item is missing.

This is what I have tryed, but in this case it do not work, if you Select an additional Item so only one e.g. AAAA is working. (AAAA and BBBB are not working)

ContainerBox is the ListView

```
Dim SelectedContainer As Integer = ContainerBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1
Dim ContainerXY As String
Dim ContainerXYAnzahl As Integer
Dim ContainerXYAnzahlAusge As Integer

For i As Integer = 0 To SelectedContainer
    ContainerXY = ""
    ContainerXYAnzahl = 0
    ContainerXYAnzahlAusge = 0
    ContainerXY = ContainerBox.SelectedItems(i).ToString.Substring    (ContainerBox.SelectedItems(i).ToString.IndexOf(":") + 1)
    For ii As Integer = 0 To ContainerBox.Items.Count - 1
        If ContainerXY = ContainerBox.Items(ii).ToString.Substring (ContainerBox.Items(ii).ToString.IndexOf(":") + 1) Then
           ContainerXYAnzahl += 1
        End If
    Next
    For ii = 0 To SelectedContainer
        If ContainerXY = ContainerBox.SelectedItems(i).ToString.Substring(ContainerBox.SelectedItems(i).ToString.IndexOf(":") + 1) Then
        ContainerXYAnzahlAusge += 1
        End If
    Next
    If ContainerXYAnzahlAusge <> ContainerXYAnzahl Then
        PresentPopup("Bitte wählen Sie alle Positionen" & Environment.NewLine & "des Container", AlertType._Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

And this is how the ListView Looks like:

[image: ListView]

Comment: You can make a list out of them then check if they are equal. Should also be possible to find differences with them.

Comment: You mean a list from the selected ones? But how can I check if all AAAA, BBBB, etc.  are selected if one of the is selected?

Comment: Would it then not just be better to foreach through the listview and automatically select all the  matching items when an  item is selected?

Comment: Take the first selected item. Then compare it with all the others (from 1 to n-1), if it's different then you don't have the same selected items.

Comment: no Auto select is not an Option, because it could also be a mistake the e.g. AAAA is selected and the User wants only CCCC.

If I compare that way I do not check if all AAAA are selected or not?! So if one AAAA is selected then all AAAA should be selected but you can additionaly select BBBB or CCCC or what else

Comment: Rereading your comments, it seems like it may be a better idea to populate the ListView with a list of distinct items in the first place to make life easier for the user.

Comment: this are all different items: every items is a Position from the order, combined with the containernumber from this Position. So one Container can have n Positions. Also a solution is, that if you selete Psotion1 with Container numer AAAA1234567 then automaticly alle Positions with the same Container number will be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedList = ListView1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim desiredList = ListView1.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem).Where(Function(i) selectedList.Select(Function(j) j.Text).Contains(i.Text))
    Dim missingItems = desiredList.Except(selectedList)
    Dim selectionsCorrect = Not missingItems.Any()
    Me.Text = $"Correct: {selectionsCorrect}; Missing items: ({String.Join(", ", missingItems.Select(Function(i) i.Text))})"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. One Addition info, the check should not be on the Change Event, It should be a a button click

Comment: You can put it where you need it. But I'd imagine it might be useful to alert the user when the form is not completed properly, before they press the button.

Comment: This is more then a hint "Take a look, you have not selected all Positions with the same Container, please check and correct this"

Comment: Also a solution is, that if you selete Psotion1 with Container numer AAAA1234567 then automaticly alle Positions with the same Container number will be selected